# How to get generified class from ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Could you please help me and clarify how should I deal with generics in Spring?

In the following example an Exception `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.Object' available` is thrown?

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        FooService<String> fooService = context.getBean(FooService.class);
        fooService.printVal();
    }

}
```

I would like to notice that if I change  generic to String type it works correctly.

```
@Service
public final class FooService<V> {

    private final V v;

    @Autowired
    public FooService(V v) {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public void printVal() {
        System.out.println(v);
    }

}
```

And simple configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("service")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public String string() {
        return "simple string";
    }

}
```

Could you please advice me what is the best way to force the snippet to work properly?

Comment: You don't use generic class definitions like that as services in the first place. When you make it a `@Service` or bean in general it has to be a finished product with a specified type. `context.getBean` is not a factory that produces objects based on your specification, it just gives you those that exist in the context. Your app crashes because even before you "request" `FooService<String>` (that should not work without a cast?) it crashes because it fails to autowire an `Object` into the `FooService` constructor because there is no definition for `V`, therefore it's `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring 4.0  it will automatically consider generics as a form of @Qualifier, as below:

```
@Autowired
private Item<String> strItem; // Injects the stringItem bean

@Autowired
private Item<Integer> intItem; // Injects the integerItem bean
```

So you should indicate the name ( in your case "string") in your constructor method.